# About the name of suggested reveiwer

Tags: paper-submission

I am going to submit a short math paper to a journal. During the process of submission I am asked to suggest the Editor \ Reviewers. In this respect, can I write the name of my co-advisor of my Ph.D as a potential reviewer? Need to say, we have a joint paper with my co-advisor.

Comment: How many years (weeks) have passed since your PhD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent joint papers are one of the first examples of conflict of interest most journals mention, see for example [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/editors/how-to-find-reviewers/32890) and [here](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-systems-and-software/policies/conflict-of-interest-guidelines-for-reviewers). Being your advisor is also explicitly mentioned as a conflict. I would avoid suggesting this person as a potential reviewer, this will at the very least raise eyebrows unless you have a very convincing reason.

Answer (score 0):

If this co-advisor is

1. not involved in the work leading to the current paper
2. is knowledgable in the area of the paper

then it would be fine to suggest the coadvisor as a reviewer.

For a more senior researcher it is quite common to personally know essentially everyone who is qualified to review their papers and to have co-published with a lot of them. Most of their papers will be reviewed by people they know.